# Haskell -- any way to turn off rebindable syntax for the case of `deriving` instances?

Tags: haskell, syntax, typeclass, deriving

There's an annoying "feature" that deriving instances are also affected by the `RebindableSyntax` extension. Example of what I want to write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
import qualified Prelude
data Color = Red | Green | Blue | Periwinkle | Fuschia deriving (Prelude.Eq, Prelude.Ord)
```

This comes up with the error " Not in scope: `ifThenElse' ".

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but would it help to move the definition into another file without `RebindableSyntax`?

Answer (score 7):

That seems like a misfeature to me--the `deriving` clause is full of built-in magic anyway, so I'm skeptical that derived instances using rebound syntax would be useful in practice. Now, if you could also rebind the `deriving` clause *itself* and use a TH splice instead... but I digress.

I suspect the simplest and easiest solution is to use different modules. Put the data type definition in its own module, use the `deriving` clause there with the Prelude functions in scope, then import the type in the module using rebindable syntax. If you need further modularity in your modules, note that `StandaloneDeriving` also exists, and would let you define the types in one module (with `RebindableSyntax` active), derive the instances in another module (without `RebindableSyntax`), and import both from modules that actually use the type.

Comment: yeah, standalone deriving would need to happen before any definitions that require the instance though, no? i.e. you couldn't write `data Color = ...` and some `foo :: Color -> Color -> Bool`, `foo c1 c2 = c1 == c2` if there's no `Eq` instance imported yet.